# Worker Scaling as application grows

Tags: php, worker

I currently have a PHP daemon that needs to run very quick iterations through a never ending loop.

It looks something like `while(true) { /* do something */ }`

The problem is my application requires this loop to do more and more actions as my application grows. However, if the loop takes too long to run then some actions might be missed. Since the loop is sending out network requests it will take some time. Currently it only sends out about 5 requests per loop, but I can already see it growing to around 50 soon.

If each request takes 1 second a 50 second loop is unacceptable. Information will be missed.

My question is how can I improve on my current system to accommodate a larger number of requests while still retaining very quick loop iterations?

I know PHP isn't ideal for this situation but at the time provided a very elegant solution. I need to use a MySQL database with JSON encoding/decoding and PHP was perfect for that. If there's a better language to do this in please let me know.

Comment: Spawn some subprocesses (`pcntl_fork`). If your loop reads input from a socket, do it afterwards. Or separate network transfers (receiving / sending).

Comment: Just want to mention: This is not a daemon. A daemon waits silently for incoming request (from TCP, socket, or whatever) to handle. This looks more like a continuos worker. Difference: First one is passive, last one is active (and polling in this case).

Comment: @mario I am not sure how I would go about using pcntl_fork in this case.

Comment: @KingCrunch Thanks for the info, you are correct. This script is a worker constantly polling data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start multiple workers, that handle a subset of urls. Many things depend on the details of what you want to achieve, but maybe a message queue (like rabbitMQ) would help too. For example: Every worker receives messages from the queue and this message contains the url they should take care of.

Comment: I've never programmed anything like this before. Honestly the thought of parent/child processes is absolutely confusing. To clarify a little, these workers need to constantly poll data from a single source and when specific information is found they need to dispatch a network request.

Comment: @SteffanLong This has (at least initially) nothing to do with forks, or child-processes. The point is, that you have a script, that fetches a message from the message queue and "do something" with the message. Now you can start this script multiple time and they all ran in parallel (the OS takes care). // Edit: Something I remembered https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque

Comment: I don't necessarily have a message queue. I have to query an external server for the information I need. Are you suggesting that I have one "worker" polling the server for information and logging it into a database and any number of worker processes to handle the information in the database?

Comment: @SteffanLong When this is sufficient, yes.

Comment: Even with that idea, though, the polling worker will not be able to poll data quick enough as my application grows. I essentially need to be able to send network requests in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

try [workaholic](http://github.com/flrngel/workaholic) instead.

It's using Redis for message queue, providing ticket system for check work is done.

and with javascript based code, it's easy to understand codes.